# R: Jordan decomposition of J

Tags: r

Currently I'm working in a model that requires a Jordan decomposition and the Jordan form of matrix. I have been working on matlab and it's really easy (just jordan(J) and done!) but not in R.

A have been trying taking into account the formula J=(V^-1)*lambda * v. Where lambda is the eigenvalue and V the eigenvector.

An example of one of my attempts:

```
A <- matrix(c(1,-3,-2,-1,1,-1,2,4,5),3,3)
A
Avalues <- eigen(A)$values
Avectors <- eigen(A)$vectors
Avalues
Avectors
solve(Avectors)%*%(diag(Avalues)%*%Avectors)
```

Another test has been:

```
J1 <- eigen(J)
Jvalues <- J1$values
Jvectors <- J1$vectors

lambda <- diag(c(Jvalues))
lambda
lambda%*%(solve(lambda)%*%Jvectors)

N <- lambda
```

But I can't achieve the proper solution (I also tried functions but the effect was the same...)

Somebody knows how to use Jordan decomposition in R properly?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, Are you sure that is Jordan decomposition or you try to diagonalise the matrix?

Comment: I've been trying to do jordan decomposition, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it in the proper way

Comment: I think that this code try to diagonalise the matrix